# Google chart API labels

Tags: api, charts

I have created a barchart with the API, but the names on the x-axis are too long and being cut off. Is there any way to fix this, like rotating them or moving them further down?

I have not been able to find anything in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Set the chartArea.height to a smaller size.

... { width: 400, chartArea: { height: 200 },  ...

You can do the same with width, depending on which axis you are having a problem with.